# nvm ls-remote N/A node doesn't get installed

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, nvm

I am trying to install node v8.16.1 using nvm. I installed nvm using `curl -k -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash`

`nvm --version` gave me `0.35.3` as expected.

But when I did `nvm install 8.16.1` I got `Version '8.16.1' not found - try nvm ls-remote to browse available versions.`

`nvm ls-remote` gave result as `N/A`.

I have tried the following solutions:

1. Adding this to ~/.bashrc `export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist`
2. Adding this to ~/.bashrc instead of above; `export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist`
3. Adding this to ~/.bashrc `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
4. sudo update-ca-certificates

But none have worked.
I have been trying for hours. Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Hi. I'm facing similar issue, but it exists only in Docker (running nvm from Centos image) and on only few machines behind corporate proxy, so I'm not even able to reproduce that on my machine. It looks like a certification problem, but still not figured out. Did you made some progress on investigating the issue?

Comment: As a workaround you can try:
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc

Comment: @Mozartos for me modifying the git-config file worked. Corporate credentials were there, which blocked insecure curl. I don't remember the exact change. Try deleting the git-config file, and then enter username pwd manually.

Answer (score 4):

echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc

Above command works for me.